# Remove Meta Tag <meta Name="GENERATOR" content="IntraWeb >on Delphi Intraweb

Tags: delphi, intraweb

I need to remove or disable meta tag "GENERATOR" from the header of Intraweb project.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta Name="GENERATOR" content="IntraWeb v14.1.14 Serial 568568568">
```

Need help on this.

I'm using Rad Studio xe7.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: No, you don't need to do this

Comment: I would also like to know why you need this to be removed.

Answer (score 5):

### IntraWeb does not support this option natively.

If you have Ultimate and use the source code, you can find the code in source that inserts this tag and change it, but you will have to re-patch with new releases.

Comment: Thanks a lot    Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

1   Create this function at UserSession:

```
procedure TIwUsersession.Remove_Meta(AForm: TIWAppForm);
var
  Frm : TIWAppForm;
Begin
  // Receive actual form....
  Frm := AForm as TIWAppForm;

  // Remove "META" "Generator" from header..........
  Frm.AddToInitProc('$("meta[name='+QuotedStr('generator')+']").remove(); ');

  // Optional.... remove other "META" or other items.....
  Frm.AddToInitProc('$("meta[name='+QuotedStr('viewport')+']").remove(); ');
  Frm.AddToInitProc('$("meta").remove(); ');
  Frm.AddToInitProc('$("script").remove(); ');
  Frm.AddToInitProc('$("link").remove(); ');
End;
```

2   At OnRender event, of each form, put:

```
Usersession.Remove_Meta(TIWAppForm(WebApplication.ActiveForm));
```